# Torsocks hangs when I try and download a file

Tags: socks, mac, torsocks, terminal

I'm using Tor v0.2.8.9 on Mac Sierra.  I start Tor like so

```
tor --CookieAuthentication 0 --HashedControlPassword "" --ControlPort 9050 --SocksPort 50003
```

HOwever when I try and get a file using torsocks (installed via homebrew), it just hangs

```
localhost:tmp myuser$ torsocks wget -q -O- http://www.google.com
```

I haven't changed any configuraitons after getting things installed.  What else do I need to do to get wget working through torsocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sometimes wget can give a hard time even using a regular proxy. Use curl like this `curl --socks5-hostname localhost:50003 http://www.google.com`

Answer (score 0):

You likely missed the step where you configure `torsocks` to use your chosen, non-default port.

The `torsocks` configuration file is normally located at `/etc/tor/torsocks.conf`, however I believe the OSX homebrew build process changes this slightly.

There you'd need to specify: `TorPort 50003`, instead of the default `TorPort 9050`.